# How to fire click event on pressing enter Jquery-UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have following JS:

```
  $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetCompanyNames",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "searchterm=" + request.term,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Name,
                                LogoUrl: item.LogoUrl,
                                InternetName :item.InternetName,
                                Name: item.Name
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
          minLength: 1
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            var innerHtml = '<a href=/Store/'+item.InternetName+'><div class="list_item_container" style="height: 60px;"><div class="image" style="float: left; margin-right: 35px;"><img src="' + item.LogoUrl + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.Name + '</div></div></a>';
            return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append(innerHtml)
        .appendTo(ul);
        };

    });
```

which renders this

[image]

This is a suggestion dropdown which shows when I enter any character in textbox like `ib` in this case,
Everything is working fine but there is only one problem when I click any item of dropdown with mouse it take me to the url which is written in its anchor tag, I want that if I scroll down with and press enter on some item it will do the same currently it's not doing anything when I press enter on a item of dropdown.

Comment: What is it meant to do when clicking on an item ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [jqFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-associate-a-url-with-each-choice-and-navigate-to-that-url-on-selection/) topic, this will help you to navigate to the url on selection made by both mouse click and pressing enter. There are few more autocomplete related FAQs too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `keyup` handler to the `a` element in your returned list items. You should be able to do that by modifying the `_renderItem` function:

```
._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var div = $('<div />'), //building using DOM elements, rather than HTML string.
        liContainer = div.clone().addClass('list_item_container').css('height', '60px'),
        img = $('<img />').attr('src', item.LogoUrl),
        imgContainer = div.clone().addClass('image').css({
            "float": "left",
            "margin-right": "35px"
        }),
        divLabel = div.clone().addClass('label').text(item.Name),
        a = $('<a />').attr('href', '/Store/' + item.InternetName);
        imgContainer.append(img);
        liContainer.append(imgContainer).append(divLabel);
        a.append(liContainer);
        a.on('keyup', function (e) { //add keyup handler to navigate to new URL on [Enter]
            if (e.which === 13) {
                window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
            }
        });
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append(a)
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```